# Make empty object keyframe values go to camera keyframes

Tags: camera

Hello fellow Blender users,

I recently followed a tutorial on achieving smooth camera movement that uses an empty object to parent the camera to it, and successfully implemented it. However, I am now curious about extracting keyframes for position, rotation, and scale of the Empty object to the Camera with the same motion. My intention is to import the camera animation into a Roblox game that I'm developing. Unfortunately, I've encountered difficulties when trying to import the animation using an empty object. Is there a way to obtain these keyframes and successfully import the camera animation into Roblox? Also sorry for any confusion that this post may cause, I don't really know how to describe my problem.

Any assistance would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Zets! You wrote "I've encountered difficulties when trying to import the animation using an empty object". It would be *very* helpful to know what those difficulties are. Can you clarify those for us?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me quickly. I'm having two difficulties with my camera animation. Firstly, when I copy the keyframes from the empty object to the camera, it just ends up moving in the same way as the empty object. Secondly, I tried importing the empty object's animation into the game engine and parenting the camera to it, but the game's camera only supports position and rotation, not scale that i used really much for the animation. I would really appreciate your help in figuring out how to overcome these challenges.